# OkHttp keeps closing connection on proceed

Tags: java, spring-boot, okhttp

I try to log (and later do some validation on it) the headers and body of the response via the OkHttp client. I have trouble finding why below code gives an exception. OkHttp just says "closed", nothing more.

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthHeaderInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private final String headerKey;
    private final String headerValue;

  @Override
    public Response intercept(final Chain chain) throws IOException {

        try {

            final Request requestWithAuthHeader = chain.request().newBuilder()
                    .header(this.headerKey, this.headerValue)
                    .build();

//        return chain.proceed(requestWithAuthHeader); -> this would work
//but this doesn't:

            final Response response = chain.proceed(requestWithAuthHeader);

            final String signatureHeader = response.headers().get("x-signature");

            log.info("x-singature={}", signatureHeader);

            return response;

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

the exception I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange$ResponseBodySource.read(Exchange.java:284)
    at okio.Buffer.writeAll(Buffer.java:1143)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readByteArray(RealBufferedSource.java:111)
    at okhttp3.ResponseBody.bytes(ResponseBody.java:136)
    at nl.rabobank.online.rass.offer.signing.common.config.apigateway.AuthHeaderInterceptor.intercept(AuthHeaderInterceptor.java:49)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
```

When I replace "intercept(final Chain chain)" with "intercept(final Interceptor.Chain chain)"  following the documentation here: https://square.github.io/okhttp/interceptors/

I still get an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: closed
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange$ResponseBodySource.read(Exchange.java:284)
    at okio.Buffer.writeAll(Buffer.java:1143)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.readByteArray(RealBufferedSource.java:111)
    at okhttp3.ResponseBody.bytes(ResponseBody.java:136)
    at nl.rabobank.online.rass.offer.signing.common.config.apigateway.AuthHeaderInterceptor.intercept(AuthHeaderInterceptor.java:49)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried this same API request with any HTTP client application like Postman? And did it worked?

Comment: yes endpoint is working, I kinda gave up and worked around it